# Union type with incompatible signatures (2349) -- is this recursive type possible?

Tags: typescript

I want to build an API that looks like this:

```
export function GET({response}) {
   return response
     .match("text/html", "<p>Hello world</p>"),
     .match("text/plain", "Hello world"),
     .match("application/json", '{"message": "Hello world"}');

}
```

I have the start of a recursive function:

```
function makeMatch(list) {

  if(list.length === 0) {
    return "end"
  }

  return {
    match: item => makeMatch(list.filter(x => x !== item))
  }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
const items = ["a", "b", "c"];

makeMatch(items).match("a").match("b").match("c"); // -> "end"
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve with TypeScript:

```
makeMatch(items).match("a"); // ok
makeMatch(items).match("x"); // does not type check, "x" is not in ["a", "b", "c"]
makeMatch(items).match("a").match("b").match("a") // does not type check, you already took "a"
```

I've gotten this far:

```
// makeMatch(emptyArray) returns "end"
function makeMatch<T>(list: []): "end"

// makeMatch(notEmptyArray) recurses
function makeMatch<T>(list: T[]): T extends "never" ? "end" : { match: <Item extends T>(item: Item) => ReturnType<typeof makeMatch<Exclude<T, Item>>> } 
                                                
function makeMatch<T>(list: T[])
{
  if(list.length === 0) {
    return "end"
  }

  return {
    match: (item: T) => makeMatch(list.filter(x => x !== item))
  }
}
```

But when I try to use the function...

```
const x = makeMatch<"json" | "text" | "csv">(["json", "text", "csv"])
```

I get this error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type `'(<Item extends "json">(item: Item) => Exclude<"json", Item> extends "never" ? "end" : { match: <Item extends Exclude<"json", Item>>(item: Item) => Exclude<Exclude<"json", Item>, Item> extends "never" ? "end" : { ...; }; }) | (<Item extends "text">(item: Item) => Exclude<...> extends "never" ? "end" : { ...; }) | (<I...'` has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.(2349)
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with TypeScript? If so, how?

Comment: @Andreas This _is_ a specific problem. I'm having trouble describing it succinctly in the title. Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: This might be a specific problem, but the old title was not. It just asked if you could type something...

Comment: @Andreas I meant type as in "add types for type checking", not literally type on the keyboard, if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY4Ggm) fit your requirements? If yes, I could write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is often not able to understand complex function body logic. So when you return multiple different things like `"end"`

```
if (items.length === 0){
  return "end"
}
```

but also an object with a function `match()`

```
return {
  match: <I extends T>(item: I) => 
    makeMatch<Exclude<T, I>>(items.filter((x): x is Exclude<T, I> => x !== item))
}
```

TypeScript will not be able to follow this conditional logic and will just infer a *union* of both cases as the return type. So we will have to make our own conditional return type for the function which will be able to differentiate the result based on the input.

The generic type `MakeMatchReturn` covers both cases:

```
type MakeMatchReturn<T> = [T] extends [never]
  ? "end" 
  : {
      match: <I extends T>(item: I) => MakeMatchReturn<Exclude<T, I>>
  }
```

`T` is a *union* of the elements of the passed array. If there is no element left in the union, we can do the check if `T` extends `never`. It's wrapped in a tuple to avoid [distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of the union elements.

The resulting `makeMatch` function will be implemented like this:

```
function makeMatch<T extends string>(items: readonly T[]): MakeMatchReturn<T>  {
    if (items.length === 0){
        return "end" as unknown as MakeMatchReturn<T>
    }
    
    return {
        match: <I extends T>(item: I) => 
            makeMatch(items.filter((x): x is Exclude<T, I> => x !== item))
    } as MakeMatchReturn<T>
}
```

`T` is a *union* of the elements of the array passed to the function. There is also the generic type `I` which is the element passed to the match function. When we recursively call the `makeMatch` function, we have to use `Exclude` to remove the current element `I` from `T`.

Also note that we have to use `as const` here. Otherwise the tuple will be *widened* to be a `string[]` which does not hold any information about individual elements anymore.

```
const items = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;

const result = makeMatch(items).match("a").match("b").match("c")
//    ^? "end"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFkCGBraTQGMAWAlaoBXAJwDsAeAFQD5YBeWAbQoF1ZoAPUaEgEwGdGJaADdoRZsFiwA-LABE3HnNiTYALlgBvVVKkBbRJiwayASTadFA6gAoAllz0bTASjo0kqdNjyFSZAFF2DAAbAh5oSgAaWFMqKlUAXxAAMwISDFA7AHsSWAMvQ2xKCy5eAT5QIjsSAHMqe0c+DSJoRB5ckPBYCgZmFw1PNCLcfGJyailtXVg7FNhG6D0+ADoQ7lrQLDpaegAGF2mZ3Va-PIVeZUQBdOQSbIB3POuEFGGjX3HKBJnkmZ1YKdxloATMDEYTOYOGV+D0Gg4ls43LQaKDjvo3t4sItlisUnYQlwiDYbOwBrB2LMBEFQuFIhQYnF3BTYABCXazRwuFwAxKwF5DLGffzUYDJYAYXKVTlLAT0BhyRByGJyABGyvkGDkrBekpIlQA3CA9dLWnwCIS6PlMSMcXwXCtwdgbIq5A6ndi1W7Hba5FqeQB6AMzAB60iAA)